# What is the >>>= operator in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, operators

What does the following Javascript statement do to `a`?

```
a >>>= b;
```

Comment: Really, you couldn't use google to find that information?

Comment: Have you tried Googling ">>>="?

Comment: Part of the goal of this site is to be the ultimate reference; I don't think simple questions are inappropriate.  And Google will ignore ">>>" in a query; you'd have to know to search on "operators" or "bitwise operators".

Comment: It is sometimes hard to find operator definitions through google as the operator itself will be treated as 'junk' by the search engine.  I remember once trying to find out what the splat operator did in Ruby.  Of course, I did not know that it was called the splat operator, and try searching for "*" :)

Comment: I can imagine why a straightforward attempt to use Google would fail - have you ever tried to search for punctuation?

Comment: @ Tinister Your search - >>>= - did not match any documents.

Comment: OK people; that'll do. We've established that it is very hard to search for unfamiliar operators if you don't already know their names. Reminds me of having to look into "Click Software"...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does the same thing as this:

```
a = a >>> b;
```

Except that `a` is only evaluated once (which has observable difference if its evaluation involves any side effects).

And `>>>` is [unsigned (logical) right shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift).

Comment: Thank you!  This is some crazy complex encoding/decoding code I am looking at here.

Comment: `a` is only "evaluated once" for `a = a >>> b` too. It's not like there is a second time where it is looked up. Both expressions return the expression's return value, not `a` (which was set to the value).

Comment: @Elijah: the assumption is that `a` is a placeholder for an arbitrary expression, not just an identifier.

Answer (score 5):

I right shifts the value in a the number of bits specified by the value in b, without maintaining the sign.

It's like the >>= operator that rights shifts a value, only that one does not change the sign of the number.

Example:

```
var a = -1;

// a now contains -1, or 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 binary

var b = 1;
a >>>= b;

// a now contains 2147483647, or 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 binary.
```

Comment: Thank you for providing that example!

Comment: Holy crap, this is some complex stuff! o_0

Answer (score 3):

It's a bitwise operator called zero-fill right shift.  It will shift the binary representation of `a` to the right by `b` places, and replace the empty items with zeros.  Then the result will be assigned to `a`.

Answer (score 0):

[Crockford points out](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html) that while JavaScript has bitwise operators like `>>>`, using them on its native double-precision floating point numbers implies converting back and forth to integers internally. They will not be as efficient as in other languages with native integer data types.